# networkx: Directed graph computes metrics for any edge

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have an (directed) edge list of following structure and length:

```
        project  donor
0       10061    119679
1       10079    120231
2       10102    121147
...
428     11456    120231
```

Then, I use following script to compute measures:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(fundedby, source='donor', target='project', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
          Degree                 = dict(G.degree),
          In_Degree              = dict(G.in_degree),
          Out_Degree             = dict(G.out_degree)
))
```

However, my final table does not only compute the measures for the items in "project" but also "donor" (note: There's no common number/id):

```
        Degree  In_Degree   Out_Degree
10061   17      17          0
10062   5       5           0
10063   7       7           0
...
120231  2       0           2
120232  1       0           1
119679  1       0           1
```

I like to compute the network measures on *project* base only. How can I either only display the project related measures, or only donor-related measures? Is there a function in networkx, or do I have to select manually via id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics you are computing (node degrees) are not computationally expensive, so what I would do is computing all of them as you do and then manually subset the output data as follows:

```
data.loc[fundedby.project.unique()]
```